# React image upload issue

Tags: reactjs

```
    uploadPictures = (event) => {
      let formData = new FormData();
      let image = event.target.files[0];

      let color = [0,153,255];

      formData.append('image', image);
      formData.append('color', color);
      let url = FormatUrl(`/store_image?`, true)
      fetch(url, {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              "Accept": '*/*',
              "type": "formData",

            },
            body:formData,
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({
            imgSrc: res.image_url
          })

        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }
```

Here i am trying to upload image to backend using above function.

But it is not working. while it is working fine for postman.
I think something is wrong with my headers

Please have a look

Comment: Any errors in console? Have you enabled CORS? Is other endpoints to the same server works fine?

Comment: yes, cors enabled. it is not cors error i checked backend

Comment: Can you post the console.log of the response